# Border not lining up for a circle

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, border

I am running into an issue in my mobile media query - anything under a 640px viewport. I have a circle that comes together and forms a full circle (see snippet), but for some reason in my media query, the circle doesn't quite line up, and I am unsure why as I am using the same math that makes it work in a desktop version.

Here is what it looks like within the 640 media query:

[image]

So how this works is I give `.circle` the same height and width. So let's say 200px for both height and width.

Then the class of `.spinner`, I divide the height and width of the `.circle` by two. So I would have 125px for height and width.

Then I set the border size, so lets use 5px. What I do is add that border size to the height and width numbers of `.spinner` and use that figure, which would be 130px to everything else ranging from `.top`, `.bottom`, `q2`, `mask`, etc.

That is how I get this to work and my math in my media query is not wrong. Does anyone see why this isn't lining up?

```css
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}

.circle {
  z-index: 99;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  background: inherit;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
}

.spinner {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid #b5f2ff;
  z-index: 10;
}

.top {
  top: 255px;
  left: 255px;
  border-radius: 0 0 255px 0;
  border-left: none;
  border-top: none;
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  transform-origin: top left;
}

.bottom {
  border-radius: 255px 0 0 0;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-right: none;
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom right;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}

.topright,
.bottomleft {
  -webkit-animation: rotate90 4s linear forwards;
  animation: rotate90 4s linear forwards;
}

.topleft,
.bottomright {
  -webkit-animation: rotate180 4s linear forwards;
  animation: rotate180 4s linear forwards;
}

.mask {
  width: 255px;
  height: 255px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  background: inherit;
  z-index: 15;
  -webkit-animation: mask 4s linear forwards;
  animation: mask 4s linear forwards;
}

.q2 {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.q4 {
  top: 255px;
  left: 255px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate90 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  20%,
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate90 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  20%,
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate180 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  40%,
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate180 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  40%,
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes mask {
  0% {
    z-index: 15
  }
  40%,
  60% {
    z-index: 4
  }
  100% {
    z-index: 15
  }
}

@keyframes mask {
  0% {
    z-index: 15
  }
  40%,
  60% {
    z-index: 4
  }
  100% {
    z-index: 15
  }
}

#circle-text {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 2.3em;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 100;
}

@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
  .circle {
    z-index: 100;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  .spinner {
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  .top {
    top: 130px;
    left: 130px;
    border-radius: 0 0 130px 0;
  }
  .bottom {
    border-radius: 130px 0 0 0;
  }
  .mask {
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
  }
  .q4 {
    top: 130px;
    left: 130px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="blue">
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="spinner top topright"></div>
    <div class="spinner top topleft"></div>
    <div class="spinner bottom bottomleft"></div>
    <div class="spinner bottom bottomright"></div>
    <div class="mask q2"></div>
    <div class="mask q4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it seems to line up for me.  what browser are you using?

Comment: By the way, it lines up in the snippet, but that is not the viewport in which I am referring to.

Comment: that web site has nothing on it.  And I moved your code to a fiddle, where it works for me in all my desktop browsers: https://jsfiddle.net/zmob5ftx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an inconsistent use of `box-sizing:border-box` in your CSS.  It's being used in media queries, so that it doesn't apply to all screen sizes.  And it would mess up your calculations.

Comment: I'm unsure of what you mean? Where do you see the `box-sizing:border-box`

Comment: I see what you mean now. Why would that have messed up the circle? I commented that code out and it works, but I am just unsure of why that had anything to do with it.

Comment: look up box-sizing.  It means that the declared width INCLUDES the padding and border, so you wouldn't add in those values separately.

Comment: Gotcha... makes sense. Thanks!